# OS is not booting, asking for BIOS update

Tags: windows-7, bios, dell-inspiron

My Dell inspiron n5050 laptop, i tried to change the OS from windows 7 sp1 to windows 7, after installtion, it is unable to restart. when i choose startup repair, it showing problem with BIOS that it is not ACPI compliant. Please contact ur system vendor for an updated BIOS.

technical info:
STOP: 0X000000A5 (......)

Initially N5050A03 was installed. Later I updated it to A04. Now In Dell website, it is showing only A03 and A05 as supported BIOS for my Laptop.
Now what to do to update the BIOS without OS

Comment: In general, You should use win 7 SP1 instead of win 7 because of security and so on. Can you go to BIOS using 'DEL' button in post screen? if you can so go to SATA properties and change it to 'IDE'.

Comment: Actually my laptop became slower,thats why  i want to install OS afresh, and i got the DVD of win 7 instead of win 7 sp1, so i tried with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you boot the recovery DVD with a thumbdrive attached you should be able to execute the command line bios update against the system bios. That A04 is not available from Dell any longer only means that Dell feels that there was an issue with that version that was sufficiently buggy to pull it from the site. You should be using your Service Code to look up the BIOS to use though and not the model because some BTO (Build To Order) laptops can be different.

Comment: Thank you Mr Rowan Hawkins, But I dont have a recovery DVD. I got only DVD of win 7. Please tell me how can i access command line with that.

Comment: Its been a while, but if you boot the win 7 DVD and select repair and recovery then you will get an option after typing in the admin password if one exists to load the recovery console. The Thumb drive needs to be attached before the boot though because otherwise it wont show up in legacy disk access mode. The DVD will usually get x:\ as its drive letter. your OS and the thumb drive may swap drives letters depending on which is enumerated first by the bios. you cant leave the bios file on the system partition because recovery console restricts where commands can be executed from.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this and come back to you

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Rowan Hawkins. I got my BIOS updated. Hats Off bro for your knowledge. I was searching the net from last two hours for this to do. And your method helped me to do

Comment: But even after updating the BIOS to A05, it is showing the same problem. i am unable to boot the system. It is showing the blue screen saying BIOS is not ACPI compliant etc.....

Comment: A quick google says that The stop error can be caused by a corrupted hibernation file. try booting off the DVD again and removing C:\Hiberfil.sys     That file still is used in Win7 to store the state of RAM to be used on system boot.